# JS Web Animations API causing weird behaviour on transform: rotate

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I am trying to allow the user to make certain HTML elements spin. The behaviour should be as such:

1. Mousebutton is pressed down (mousedown event fired)
2. Mouse is moved around while button still pressed (mousemove event fired)
3. Mousebutton is released (mouseup fired)

During 2), if the user moves the mouse along the x-axis one way, the elements spin one way, and if the user moves the mouse along the x-axis the other way, the elements spin the other way.

Once 3) happens, the boxes are supposed to **snap** to some pre-determined angles (0,90,180,270 deg or the equivalent in radians). But they are not supposed to snap instantenously. Rather, I'd like to have a short animation play that "eases them" or "slow-snaps" them into place.

My implementation of this was working fine until I tried to add the slow-snap animations. If I do not animate, but instead just set the CSS transform:rotate value, everything behaves as expected (minus the animations, of course). But once I added the animations, things started getting weird: On the first cycle of above 3 events (mousedown, mousemove, mousemove), the objects rotate nicely while the mouse is being dragged, and ease into place once the mouse button is released. However, on the second (and any subsequent) cycle of the events, the animations and rotations of the objects become "erratic", to the degree that I cannot get to the bottom of what is causing this.

Below is a short gif that shows this. The top 4 squares are animated to ease into place, and the bottom 4 squares just get "hard-snapped" into place. Notice how on the second and third click, the upper row starts becoming misaligned during rotations.

[image]

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qz1nwy8g/6/) which uses below JavaScript and demonstrates the behaviour

```
Array.prototype.max = function() {
  return Math.max.apply(null, this);
};

Array.prototype.min = function() {
  return Math.min.apply(null, this);
};

let animateContainer = document.getElementById("animate-container")
let doNotAnimateContainer = document.getElementById("do-not-animate-container")
createScene();


const angles = [0,Math.PI/2, Math.PI,3*Math.PI/2]
const squares = document.getElementsByClassName("square")

var primaryMouseButtonDown = false;

function setPrimaryButtonState(e) {
  var flags = e.buttons !== undefined ? e.buttons : e.which;
  primaryMouseButtonDown = (flags & 1) === 1;
}


function getRotation(elem)
{
 var rotString = elem.style.transform;
 rotString = rotString.substr(rotString.indexOf("rotate(")+7);
 rotString = rotString.substr(0, rotString.indexOf(")")-3);
return Number(rotString)
}

function getNearestAngle(elem)
{
    var differences = []
  angles.forEach((angle) => {
    differences.push(Math.abs(getRotation(elem)-angle))
  })
  var nearestAngle = differences.min();
  var index = differences.indexOf(nearestAngle);
  return angles[index];
}

function createScene()
{
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {
    var square = document.createElement("div")
    square.className="square"
    square.classList.add("crossed")
    square.classList.add("prevent-select")
    square.style.transform=`rotate(${i*Math.PI/2}rad)`
    square.innerHTML = i
    animateContainer.appendChild(square)
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {
    var square = document.createElement("div")
    square.className="square"
    square.classList.add("crossed")
    square.classList.add("prevent-select")
    square.style.transform=`rotate(${i*Math.PI/2}rad)`
    square.innerHTML = i
    doNotAnimateContainer.appendChild(square)
    }
}




document.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {setPrimaryButtonState(e)});
document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {setPrimaryButtonState(e), handleMouseMove(e)});
document.addEventListener("mouseup", (e) => {setPrimaryButtonState(e), handleMouseUp(e)});


function handleMouseMove(e){
    
  if(primaryMouseButtonDown === true)
    {
    var mouseMovement = {x:e.movementX, y: e.movementY}

    for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; ++i)
    {
      var square = squares[i]
      var oldRotation = getRotation(square)
      newRotation = (oldRotation + e.movementX/100) % (2*Math.PI)
      square.style.transform = `rotate(${newRotation}rad)`
        if (i == 0)
      {
        console.log("angle is now " + newRotation + " radians.")
      }
    }
    }
}

function handleMouseUp(e)
{
    
  for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; ++i)
  {
    var square = squares[i];
    var nearestRotation = getNearestAngle(square);
    var currentRotation = getRotation(square);
    if (i == 0)
    {
        console.log("MouseUp. currentRotation: " + currentRotation + ". nearestRotation: " + nearestRotation)
    }
    var difference = currentRotation - nearestRotation;
    var newRotation = currentRotation - difference;
    
    if (square.parentElement.id=="animate-container")
    {
      const animation = square.animate([
        {transform: `rotate(${currentRotation}rad)`},
        {transform: `rotate(${newRotation}rad)`}
      ],
      {
        fill: "forwards",
        duration: 1000,
        iterations: 1
      });

      animation.addEventListener("finish", () => {console.log("finished-square"); animation.commitStyles(); animation.cancel();})
        }
    else
    {
        square.style.transform = `rotate(${newRotation}rad)`;
    }
    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `animation.commitStyles()` is called, it seems to write the `rotate()`s with degree units (`deg`). The `getRotation()` function seems to return the number in the `rotate()` `transform` style but does not account for the unit. Places where the `getRotation()` function is called seem to assume the returned number is in radians so when a degree amount is returned, the calculations are incorrect.

Consider accounting for possible `deg` units and convert if needed in `getRotation()`:

```js
function getRotation(elem)
{
  const { transform } = elem.style;
  const [, amount, unit] = /\brotate\((.+?)(rad|deg)\)/.exec(transform);
  return unit === 'deg'
    ? parseFloat(amount) * Math.PI / 180
    : parseFloat(amount)
}
```

Full example:

```js
Array.prototype.max = function() {
  return Math.max.apply(null, this);
};

Array.prototype.min = function() {
  return Math.min.apply(null, this);
};


let animateContainer = document.getElementById("animate-container")
let doNotAnimateContainer = document.getElementById("do-not-animate-container")
createScene();


const angles = [0, Math.PI / 2, Math.PI, 3 * Math.PI / 2]
const squares = document.getElementsByClassName("square")

var primaryMouseButtonDown = false;

function setPrimaryButtonState(e) {
  var flags = e.buttons !== undefined ? e.buttons : e.which;
  primaryMouseButtonDown = (flags & 1) === 1;
}


function getRotation(elem) {
  const { transform } = elem.style;
  const [, amount, unit] = /\brotate\((.+?)(rad|deg)\)/.exec(transform);
  return unit === 'deg' ?
    parseFloat(amount) * Math.PI / 180 :
    parseFloat(amount)
}

function getNearestAngle(elem) {
  var differences = []
  angles.forEach((angle) => {
    differences.push(Math.abs(getRotation(elem) - angle))
  })
  var nearestAngle = differences.min();
  var index = differences.indexOf(nearestAngle);
  return angles[index];
}






function createScene() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var square = document.createElement("div")
    square.className = "square"
    square.classList.add("crossed")
    square.classList.add("prevent-select")
    square.style.transform = `rotate(${i*Math.PI/2}rad)`
    square.innerHTML = i
    animateContainer.appendChild(square)
  }



  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var square = document.createElement("div")
    square.className = "square"
    square.classList.add("crossed")
    square.classList.add("prevent-select")
    square.style.transform = `rotate(${i*Math.PI/2}rad)`
    square.innerHTML = i
    doNotAnimateContainer.appendChild(square)
  }
}




document.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
  setPrimaryButtonState(e)
});
document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  setPrimaryButtonState(e), handleMouseMove(e)
});
document.addEventListener("mouseup", (e) => {
  setPrimaryButtonState(e), handleMouseUp(e)
});


function handleMouseMove(e) {

  if (primaryMouseButtonDown === true) {
    var mouseMovement = {
      x: e.movementX,
      y: e.movementY
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; ++i) {
      var square = squares[i]
      var oldRotation = getRotation(square)
      newRotation = (oldRotation + e.movementX / 100) % (2 * Math.PI)
      square.style.transform = `rotate(${newRotation}rad)`
      if (i == 0) {
        console.log("angle is now " + newRotation + " radians.")
      }
    }
  }
}

function handleMouseUp(e) {

  for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; ++i) {
    var square = squares[i];
    var nearestRotation = getNearestAngle(square);
    var currentRotation = getRotation(square);
    if (i == 0) {
      console.log("MouseUp. currentRotation: " + currentRotation + ". nearestRotation: " + nearestRotation)
    }
    var difference = currentRotation - nearestRotation;
    var newRotation = currentRotation - difference;

    if (square.parentElement.id == "animate-container") {
      const animation = square.animate([{
          transform: `rotate(${currentRotation}rad)`
        },
        {
          transform: `rotate(${newRotation}rad)`
        }
      ], {
        fill: "forwards",
        duration: 1000,
        iterations: 1
      });

      animation.addEventListener("finish", () => {
        console.log("finished-square");
        animation.commitStyles();
        animation.cancel();
      })
    } else {
      square.style.transform = `rotate(${newRotation}rad)`;
    }

  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.square {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  margin: 20px;
  color: white;
}

.crossed {
  background: linear-gradient(to top left, blue 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) calc(50% - 0.8px), rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) calc(50% + 0.8px), blue 100%), linear-gradient(to top right, blue 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) calc(50% - 0.8px), rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) calc(50% + 0.8px), blue 100%);
}

.prevent-select {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  /* Safari */
  -ms-user-select: none;
  /* IE 10 and IE 11 */
  user-select: none;
  /* Standard syntax */
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="animate-container" class="container">

  </div>

  <div id="do-not-animate-container" class="container">

  </div>
</body>
```